# get objects from a list in LIFO order? (Last-In-First-Out) (Beginner)

Tags: java, list, arraylist, linked-list, lifo

(Please, bear in mind that this is a beginners problem)

I have two classes; `MailItem` and `MailServer`. I have a testing class, where I make and send MailItems to my MailServer. I sent to MailItems to one specific user, and I expect to retreive these in LIFO-order(Last-In-First-Out), so the lastest to be sent have to be the first I recieve.

Here are my classes.

**MailItem class:**

```
public class MailItem
{
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private String message;
    private String subject;

    public MailItem(String from, String to, String message, String subject)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.message = message;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getFrom()
    {
        return from;
    }

    public String getTo()
    {
        return to;
    }

    public String getSubject(){
        return subject;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
        return message;
    }

    public void print()
    {
        System.out.println("From: " + from);
        System.out.println("To: " + to);
        System.out.println("Message: " + message);
        System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
    }
}
```

**MailServer class:**

```
public class MailServer
{
    private List<MailItem> items;
    private HashMap<String, List<MailItem>> hashmap;

    public int howManyMessages(){
        return items.size();
    }

    public int howManyUsers(){
        return hashmap.size();
    }

    public MailServer()
    {
        items = new LinkedList<MailItem>();
        hashmap = new HashMap<String, List<MailItem>>();
    }

    public int howManyMailItems(String who)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for(MailItem item : items) {
            if(item.getTo().equals(who)) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public MailItem getNextMailItem(String who)
    {
        Iterator<MailItem> it = items.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            MailItem item = it.next();
            if(item.getTo().equals(who)) {
                it.remove();
                return item;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void post(MailItem item)
    {
        if(!isEmpty(item)){
            items.add(item);
        }
    }

    private boolean isEmpty(MailItem mail){
        if(mail.getFrom() == "" || mail.getTo() == ""){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public int createMailbox(String user){
        if(hashmap.containsKey(user)){
            return 0;
        }
        List<MailItem> mil = new ArrayList<MailItem>();
        hashmap.put(user, mil);
        return 1;
    }

    public int createMailbox(String[] users){
        int createdBoxes = 0;
        for(String user: users){
            int created = createMailbox(user);
            if(created == 1){
                createdBoxes++;
            }
        }
        return createdBoxes;
    }

    private List<MailItem> getMailbox(String who){
        if(hashmap.containsKey(who)){
            List<MailItem> ls = hashmap.get(who);
            return ls;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Here is how my test look like:**

```
@Test
    public void testReceiveOrder(){
        mailServer.post(mess1User1to2);
        mailServer.post(mess2User1to2);
        assertEquals(mess2User1to2,mailServer.getNextMailItem("user2"));
    }
```

When I run this test, I retrieve these emails in a FIFO(First-In-First-Out) manner. Instead of retrieving the mail called *mess2User1to2*, I get *mess1User1to2*. I tried using LinkedList to retrieve them in LIFO, but It did not work for me. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `post` method adds the item to the end of the list and your `getNextMailItem` method starts searching for the item in the front of the list. Therefore you get FIFO (=queue) behaviour.

To change this either start searching at the end of the list:

```
public MailItem getNextMailItem(String who) {
    ListIterator<MailItem> it = items.listIterator(items.size());
    while(it.hasPrevious()) {
        MailItem item = it.previous();
        if(item.getTo().equals(who)) {
            it.remove();
            return item;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Alternatively you could instead add the items to the front of the list, but I haven't checked, if this breaks any other methods:

```
private LinkedList<MailItem> items;

public void post(MailItem item) {
    if(!isEmpty(item)){
        items.addFirst(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the second part since it did not break other methods.